# Multiple mat-header-rows not working with version 5.x angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to have multiple headers as shown in
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-aazxkz?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

version of material: "@angular/material": "5.2.x"

I am unable to achieve the same since, only one header(the first one) gets rendered. Please help me with this. I want to achieve the same without upgrading my version. please let me know if I have any alternatives here.

My code:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!--- Note mat-header-cellat mat-header-cellese columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on mat-header-celle row definition" -->
  
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Header row first group -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-1">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center;" [attr.colspan]="2">
        first group
      </mat-header-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Header row second group -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-2">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="2"> Second group </mat-header-cell>
    </ng-container>
    
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['header-row-1', 'header-row-2']"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

Even though, i have multiple mat-header-row, only the first one gets rendered.

[image]

Comment: With angular 5 it is not possible to do so. Official documentation doesn't have any example as such. I did try to create your issue and it seems to render only one header row as you mentioned.

Comment: oh okay. thanks for the clarifications.. so the only way we can make it is if we increase the version of material angular.

Comment: Yes if you upgrade your version, you won't face the issue.